# .Net Maui Shell navigation, is it possible to keep previouse page state as in NavigationPage (old way)?

Tags: shell, scroll, navigation, maui, collectionview

I have a listing page with a CollectionView control, when item clicked it opens a details page, when back button pressed on details page, i lose the scoll position on listing page!
With Shell navigation the previouse page is rerendered everytime we back to it! so scroll position is lost! data needs to be bind again, and it's hard save the last scroll position and restore it, and it's not the desired behaviour!

I tried the same scenario with NavigationPage, using Navigation.Push(DetailsPage), and for back Navigation.Pop(), this keeps listing page state with no changes, scroll position not reset! everything works as expected!

Is it possible to achive the same thing with Shell navigation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I used Shell.Current.GoToAsync method to navigate to DetailPage without losing CollectionView scoll position. Could you please show more relevant code  or provide a [minial reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us reproduce issue.

Answer (score 0):

I achived the desired behaviour with shell navigation by registering the listing page and it's ViewModel as singltones

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).